# How do I fetch a value from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making habit tracker app with react native.
want to import data from firebase and get the value and adjust it.

```
const days = [
  'M',
  'T',
  'W',
  'T',
  'F',
  'S',
  'S'
];

const Calendar = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.calendarWrap}>
      
      {days.map((day,index)=>{

        const [btnPush, setBtnPush] = useState('');

        const completeTask = () =>{
          setBtnPush(!btnPush);
        };

        const PushButton = btnPush === index ;
        
        return(
          <View style={styles.dayWrap} key={index}>
          <Text style={styles.day}>{day}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity 
            style={[styles.weekCircle, PushButton &&{backgroundColor: '#000'} ]}
            onPress={() => completeTask }
            ></TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
  
        )
      })}

    </View>
```

and I wrote firebase like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWxTt.png)

I want to modify date data in firestore and if it has 'true' I want to adjust style like this:

`{[styles.weekCircle, PushButton &&{backgroundColor: '#000'} ]}`

Comment: Shouldn't you try to connect to Firebase with Node.js instead of React.js? Firebase is a backend service and people will abuse your database if you access it through React.

Comment: I'm learning about firebase but quite hard for me though, thanks for answers! I'll check about documentation :)

Comment: SO is for help with existing code and is not a code writing service. Please include the code you've attempted so we can take a look. If you need to get started, see the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) and take a moment to review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)